# Is it possible to have a feed of "today's featured article" from Wikipedia in an RSS reader?

Tags: rss, wikipedia

I'd like to add an RSS feed of "today's featured article" and possibly "in the news" to my RSS reader. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the URI for Wikipedia's Featured Article atom feed:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=featuredfeed&feed=featured&feedformat=atom

Comment: Always ass essential part of the link into your answer.

Comment: Nice! It's a shame there are no tags to filter by category, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Information about Wikipedia's feeds is on the page [Wikipedia:Syndication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aSyndication).

The two feeds are provided by third parties.

According to the page, the feed of “Today's Featured Article” is at http://feeds.feedburner.com/WikipediaTodaysFeaturedArticle.

The feed of “In the news” was created by me some time ago and it's available at http://itn.svick.org/. (The same news item will sometimes appear twice in the feed, if the page title the news item links to changes.)

Comment: I've stumbled across that feed before, but sadly, it appears to be broken.

Comment: It seems you're right, I didn't actually check it. There seems to be another feed that actually works, I have updated the answer.

Comment: The "feedburner" feed linked above appears to be broken. Last entry available: "Ringo Starr", 7/7/2015

Answer (score 0):

you can try generate date in url:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:FeedItem/featured/20181226000000/en
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:FeedItem/featured/20181226000000/en
```

> 20181226 => 2018/12/26

No guarantees!

Comment: Thanks but that's not at all what I'm after. I was looking for an RSS feed of all featured articles as they come out.